# How to get Max value from last two digits out of max 3 in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, max, trim, digits

I want to trim some numbers to two digits and get the max value from it.

My table column is called "thousands" (int4) and has values like:

- 912
- 905
- 900
- 11
- 7
- 6

I expect to receive the value 12, because after trimming the numbers to a max. of two digits, 912 should be transformed to 12 which is higher than 11, but I receive 7 using the query:

```
SELECT MAX(RIGHT("thousands"::varchar, 2)) 
FROM "numbers"
```

I guess RIGHT([string], [number of digits from right to left]) is messing up when the value has less digits than requested, but I don't know how to achieve the demanded solution. Can anybody help please?

Comment: SELECT MAX(RIGHT("thousands"::varchar, 2)::int) 
FROM "numbers"

Comment: This one also works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5dfee71d4771049f75b4ed56f9979e8f)

`RIGHT()` returns an `text` output. So, `MAX()` is applied to this output and uses alphabetical order. In this order, `7` comes after `12` because `7 > 1` (`1` as the first character of `12`). To avoid this, you could cast the `RIGHT()` result into type `int` afterwards before using `MAX()`:

```
SELECT
    MAX(RIGHT(thousands::text, 2)::int)
FROM t
```

The better and faster ways would be using numeral operations instead of double casting your values. So, the last to digit of a number can be calculated using the modulo operation `%`:

```
SELECT
    MAX(thousands % 100)
FROM t
```